# mempty with different definition depending on whether mempty is left or right arg?

Tags: haskell, monoids, semigroup

I have the following datatype and semigroup instance:

```
data Or a b =
  Fst a
  | Snd b deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Semigroup (Or a b) where
  (<>) (Fst a) (Fst b) = Fst b
  (<>) (Snd a) (Fst b) = Snd a
  (<>) (Fst a) (Snd b) = Snd b
  (<>) (Snd a) (Snd b) = Snd a
```

I want to make a monoid instance for the type above, but I do not see how to do it. If I use the following definition

```
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (Or a b) where
  mempty = (Fst mempty)
  mappend = (<>)
```

it will work on all pairs of input to `<>`, except the one where I `mappend`

```
(Fst a) <> mempty
```

which will evaluate to `mempty`.

How do I fix this so that the `mempty` is valid? It seems like it cannot be done without some new syntax or concepts since it hinges on whether the mempty is to the left or right...

Comment: It doesn't seem like you actually have a monoid here, to be honest.  There _isn't_ an identity element.

Comment: Strange. Implementing a monoid for it is an exercise from the Haskell book, http://haskellbook.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a perfectly good (and simpler) semigroup which always takes its first argument:

```
newtype FirstS a = FirstS a
instance Semigroup (FirstS a) where
    a <> b = a
```

Unfortunately, it is not a monoid because -- except for trivial choices of wrapped type -- there is no left identity of this operation. The standard `First` type patches `FirstS` by adding a distinguished identity element, thus:

```
newtype First a = First (Maybe a)
instance Semigroup (First a) where
    First Nothing <> b = b
    a <> First Nothing = a
    a <> b = a -- this clause is exactly as before
```

Then it is easy to write the `Monoid` instance by choosing `mempty = First Nothing`. You can pull a similar trick by adding a distinguished identity element to your type:

```
data Or a b = Fst a | Snd b | Neither
instance Semigroup (Or a b) where
    Neither <> b = b
    a <> Neither = a
    -- the remainder of the clauses are as before
```

This makes the choice of `mempty = Neither` quite easy.

This pattern is so frequently useful that it actually has a newtype wrapper in [`semigroups`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option), so that you could also write this patched type using your original `Or a b` type as simply `Option (Or a b)` and get the `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances for free.